# AngularJS: Header tag breaks ngSwitch

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I use `<h3>` tags inside the ngSwitch in my html, the entire thing breaks.

Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngSwitch', required by directive 'ngSwitchWhen', can't be found!

If i replace the `<h3>` tag with a `<strong>` tag for example then it works.

You can try out the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb8aatyz/1/

**Html #1**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p data-ng-if="::type" data-ng-switch="type">
    <span><h3>Account type:</h3></span>
    <span data-ng-switch-when="facebook" class="ico-fb inline"></span>
    <span data-ng-switch-when="google" class="ico-google inline"></span>
    <span data-ng-switch-default="" class="ico-email inline"></span>
    <span>{{ type }}</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

**Html #2**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p data-ng-if="::type" data-ng-switch="type">
    <span><strong>Account type:</strong></span>
    <span data-ng-switch-when="facebook" class="ico-fb inline"></span>
    <span data-ng-switch-when="google" class="ico-google inline"></span>
    <span data-ng-switch-default="" class="ico-email inline"></span>
    <span>{{ type }}</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like all the block level tags beside headers break ngSwitch(p and div for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the `h3`, or `div` inside a `p` is invalid in any HTML standard. In this case, if you use `inspect elements` in the browser, you will find the `h3` closes `p` automatically, which makes ngSwitch breaks.

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291608/1867608

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div data-ng-if="type" data-ng-switch="type">
        <h3>Account Type:</h3>
        <span data-ng-switch-when="facebook" class="ico-fb inline"></span>
        <span data-ng-switch-when="google" class="ico-google inline"></span>
        <span data-ng-switch-default="" class="ico-email inline"></span>
        <span>{{ type }}</span>
    </div>
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(function($controllerProvider) {
    $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.type = "email";
});
```

You can not use block element inside inline tag and there is no need to use :: before type in the ng-if and you can also use ng- instead of data-ng-

Answer (score 0):

It seems like replacing the `p` tag with `div` resolves the problem but unfortunately I cannot explain this..

Answer (score -1):

You can not use a block element (h3 tag) inside an inline tag (span).
See this: [h1 and the span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513136/h1-and-the-span)

Comment: Hey, you are right about the tags, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem in this case. Even if I take out the (span) tag or switch them around (put span inside h3) it still has the same issue.